# Decrpyt SQLITE3 database

Tags: sqlite, python-3.6

I don't know what happened exactly, but I was browsing my table and the data within. I closed the database and then modified it a bit using a script and tried again to open the database. However it then came up with this screen [image]

I'm confused on what happened? Did I accidentally encrypt the data? If so, how can I decrypt the data in the database, without having to re-do the entire database

Comment: "modified it a bit using a script" - what kind of script?

Comment: A script that inserts IP Address into the database

Comment: That's not nearly enough information.  Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.